# How to get decimal value from Slider?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Want to be able to get a value of 25.4, for example.

```
<Slider 
x:Name="Slider" 
Maximum="100.0" 
Minimum="0.0" 
Value="25.0" 
TickFrequency="2.0" 
TickPlacement="Inline">
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add StepFrequency:

```
StepFrequency="0.1"
```